# What plants will bloom in the fall in my yard in Seattle?

Tags: plant-recommendations, planting, fall-gardening, outdoor

I'm looking for suggestions on what to plant in my front yard. I live in Seattle and summer will be over within a month, so I would like something that blossoms later in the year to give it some color during cloudy days. Seattle doesn't get much sun, it's often cloudy and rainy, so I'm looking for something that can survive this type of climate, and requires little maintenance.

Update: After some research I landed on Blue Fescue (Festuca glauca) and Periwinkle (Vinca minor). The latter has flowers, the first is a kind of grass. I will be ordering seeds and plant them mid September.

[image]

Comment: @Sue I've updated the post with two suggestions.

Comment: What do you think about annuals? Pansies and some others can bloom in the fall, and some can overwinter. Or ornamental Kale?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with sites like this are there is often too little information about the whole year- as in where are the frost pockets, dark shaded bits and at what times of the day, soil type, pH, drainage, aspect, height and elevation, and more importantly, what you expect to do here- First thing I would do is measure out the site and then you can try to fix a budget. That will influence your choice of plants as if its a small site one won't want big stuff in there, if the sites got bad drainage or shallow soil- then again things that root deeply are out, again shade also affect your choice-(think evergreens and not too interesting stuff here) do you want a theme, or a reflection of life style, are you allergic to anything, are there children involved(no big bright toxic berries)we need info before we can think offer better answers. By the look of the site the soil looks knackered! and shady, perhaps a bit exposed and a cold looking aspect- more info please